# pull queues authorization from compute

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api-client, google-compute-engine, pull-queue

I'm trying to access a pull queue from google compute with the compute OAuth token using python

```
from oauth2client import gce
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2

credentials = gce.AppAssertionCredentials('')
http = httplib2.Http()
http=credentials.authorize(http)
credentials.refresh(http)
service = build('taskqueue', 'v1beta2', http=http)
tq=service.taskqueues()
tq.get(project=MY_APPENGINE_PROJECT, taskqueue=PULL_QUEUE_NAME, getStats=True).execute()
```

I keep getting HttpError 403 "you are not allowed to make this api call"

please help, what configure have I missing?

thanks,
Shay

Comment: Did you pass in the taskqueue service scope when you started the instance?  https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication has more info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Thanks to @Shay for asking this question, the issue he encountered is no longer an issue, as we have allowed aliases to work (when relevant) in the Task Queue API.

For posterity here is the original answer below:

---

Two of the most common mistakes I have seen are:

1. Forgetting to include the `s~` in your App Engine Project. For example, if your application ID is `my-awesome-app`, then you are calling

   ```
   tq.get(project='my-awesome-app', taskqueue=PULL_QUEUE_NAME...
   ```

   when you should be calling

   ```
   tq.get(project='s~my-awesome-app', taskqueue=PULL_QUEUE_NAME...
   ```
2. Forgetting to add the Compute service account to the [task queue ACL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Defining_Pull_Queues) in `queue.yaml`. To do this, you need to get the service account associated with your project and add it to the `acl`:

   ```
   queue:
   - name: pull-queue
     mode: pull
     acl:
     - writer_email: 123845678986@project.gserviceaccount.com    # can do all
   ```

   and of course this would mean `PULL_QUEUE_NAME = 'pull-queue'` here. Also note, `123845678986@project.gserviceaccount.com` should be replaced with the service account for your Compute Engine instance.

Comment: BTW the service account can be found in the api console under team on the bottom part of the page

Comment: I still got `Insufficient Permission`, see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479204/full-api-access-does-not-work-for-taskqueue What IAM roles has to be set for the instance account?