# Google App Engine Task Queue: googleapi: Error 500: Backend Error

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I've defined a pull queue for my app engine application and want to fill it from outside via the REST api.
Unfortunately it doesn't work, I always get an error 500: backend error.
Even if I try to fill it with the api explorer from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/taskqueue/rest/tasks/insert).

It responses:

```
500 Internal Server Error

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: looking at the logs would be a good start.

Comment: @Frank, did you find out what caused this? I have the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you paste your code that is doing the leasing?  One common mistake is forgetting to include the s~ in your App Engine Project. For example, if your application ID is my-awesome-app, then you are calling

```
tq.get(project='my-awesome-app', taskqueue=PULL_QUEUE_NAME...
```

when you should be calling

```
tq.get(project='s~my-awesome-app', taskqueue=PULL_QUEUE_NAME...
```

(thanks to bossylobster for this original answer: [pull queues authorization from compute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063073/pull-queues-authorization-from-compute))

Answer (score 3):

Also it turns out you must supply the `queueName` in the JSON body, in addition to `payloadBase64`, as discovered by Frank Ren in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/taskqueue/google-appengine/ojW5PWbFNTA/hnym0zjUHHcJ)