# What does it mean the "s~" prefix in the Google Cloud project id name?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

There is described a need to include of the "s~" prefix to the Google Cloud project id, see answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063073/pull-queues-authorization-from-compute/17071255#17071255).

**What does mean the "s~" prefix in front of a project id and where can I find a description of that?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For now it means that the app in hosted in north america. e~ means it's hosted in europe.

Comment: Thanks! And please can you add there a link to some google cloud documentation which describes it?

Comment: Speaking of hosting.. Is it possible to host it in Europe?

Comment: it's really implementation detail, there is no need to describe it publicly.

Comment: Hi, I need to know the prefix to obtain a compatible legacy key as described here: https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/keys.html#google.cloud.datastore.key.Key.to_legacy_urlsafe

So is it possible to know the prefix programmatically?

Same as this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271606/how-can-i-obtain-programatically-the-location-prefix-of-an-app-engine-project-id

Comment: I believe it's a implementation detail at that time (2014?) so no public doc about this.

But as the Python 3 datastore client library described, I think it's necessary to have a way to know the prefix some where. I cannot even find it in the GAE project dashboard or settings.