# How can I obtain programatically the location prefix of an App Engine project ID?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am using Google App Engine standard in python 3.7 and need to obtain the legacy safe url for an Entity in the Datastore using its Key.

In order to achieve this I need to know the location_prefix.

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/key.html#Key.to_legacy_urlsafe

How can I obtain that value programatically in Python for a given project id?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?: [Retrieving Entities from Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#retrieving_entities)

[appengine/standard/ndb/entities/snippets.pyView on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/6f5f3bcb81779679a24e0964a6c57c0c7deabfac/appengine/standard/ndb/entities/snippets.py)

> You can also use an entity's key to obtain an encoded string suitable
>   for embedding in a URL:

```
url_string = sandy_key.urlsafe()
```

This produces a result like 'agVoZWxsb3IPCxIHQWNjb3VudBiZiwIM' which can later be used to reconstruct the key and retrieve the original entity:

```
sandy_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=url_string)
sandy = sandy_key.get()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, unless you provide the location_prefix, the legacy url you are going to obtain is not going to be correct.