# Full API Access does not work for Taskqueue

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a new Debian GCE VM which has full access to Google Cloud services. I'm able to access most of the services from this instance. However I'm unable to access task queues.

```
host:~/home$ curl 
"https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta2/projects/project/taskqueues/
my-queue/tasks" -H "Authorization":"Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
{
 "error": {
   "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
 ],
"code": 403,
"message": "Insufficient Permission"
}
}
```

From my other VM which has fine grained access to individual services, I'm able to access task queue. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, I got the answer from Google about TaskQueue REST API:

> The REST API has it's own auth mechanism using access control lists.
>   Since this API is experimental, we have no plans of offering full IAM
>   integration. Instead, we are building a new API which will replace
>   this one with full IAM support.

A workaround is to set export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/servicek‌​ey.json`.